# fstab entry to mount NFS with password

Tags: nfs, mount, fstab

i need mount at boot a disk using NFS, to mount manually from console i type:

```
mount //192.168.0.1/NASShare -o username=administrator,password=pass /mnt/NAS
```

To `/etc/fstab` i added this line:

```
192.168.0.1:/NASShare  /mnt/NAS  nfs user=administrator,password=pass  0 0
```

But at reboot the disk is not mounted, where is the error?

Comment: What error do you get when you manually try to mount it?  `mount -a`   What error(s) show up in your NAS logs?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the error, i need insert `username` instead of `user`

```
192.168.0.1:/NASShare  /mnt/NAS  nfs username=administrator,password=pass  0 0
```

Comment: if you're mounting a Synology Nas shared drive, instead of the IP of the host, use `SynologyNas.local`

Answer (score 7):

You don't specify in your question whether you are trying to use NFSv3 or NFSv4, but neither supports a `password` parameter.  The `user` parameter isn't even recognized by [`NFS`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/nfs) or [`mount.nfs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.nfs), it is handled purely by [`mount`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount), and essentially allows non-root users to mount the filesystem.  The `user` parameter (or `users`, if un-mounting is also desired) can be specified by itself with no additional arguments (i.e. `mount -t nfs -o user`) and indicates that any user can mount the filesystem.

Even after supplying the `user` option to `mount`, an NFS export that is listed in `/etc/fstab` will not be mounted as the logged-in user, because `/etc/fstab` is sourced before any user is logged in, so it will still be mounted as root.  All working solutions that require supplying the `user` option to `mount` currently rely on also supplying the `noauto` option, and then running the mount command manually *after login*, as the user that you wish to mount the NFS export with.

NFS  does not support sending plaintext passwords over the network, so you should never find yourself specifying a password as a mount option.